# Trigger Not Firing

Tags: trigger

I have an after trigger that fires when an Opportunity is updated.  I'm having an issue because when I look for the Account ID related to the Opportunity, it is returning as Null even though the Opportunity is absolutely linked to an Account (system debug at line 25).  All the other variables in the debug statement return as expected.  Does anyone know why the Account field does not?  Thanks,

***Trigger:***

```
ClassOpp2Account updater14 = new ClassOpp2Account();
            updater14.mgdUpdates(Trigger.new);
```

***Trigger Class:***

```
public class ClassOpp2Account{

    public void mgdUpdates(List<Opportunity> MgdAcctUpdates){

    Map<Id,Account> acctMap = new Map<Id,Account>();
    Set<id> Ids = new Set<id>();

    String recordTypeName = 'Renewals';
    Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMapByName = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
    Schema.RecordTypeInfo rtInfo =  rtMapByName.get(recordTypeName);
    id recType = rtInfo.getRecordTypeId();

    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        for (Opportunity opp : MgdAcctUpdates)
        {
                Ids.add(opp.Account.Id);
            }

     Map<Id,Account> acctMap2 = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,Name,Managed_Renewal_Date__c,Managed_Term__c,Managed_Value__c
                                                    FROM Account
                                                    WHERE Id in :Ids]);

        for (Opportunity opp2 : MgdAcctUpdates){

system.debug('***#*** IsClosed: '+opp2.IsClosed+' Stage: '+opp2.StageName+' Opp Rec Type: '+opp2.RecordTypeId+' Rec Type: '+recType+' Acct Name: '+opp2.Account);
            if(opp2.RecordTypeId == recType && opp2.IsClosed == true){

            if(acctMap2.containsKey(opp2.Account.Id)){

                Account acct = acctMap2.get(opp2.Account.Id);
            if(acctMap2.get(opp2.Account.Id).Managed_Renewal_Date__c < opp2.Renewal_Date_Next__c || acctMap2.get(opp2.Account.Id).Managed_Renewal_Date__c == null) {
                    acct.Managed_Renewal_Date__c = opp2.Renewal_Date_Next__c;
                    acct.Managed_Term__c = opp2.Term__c;
                    acct.Managed_Value__c = opp2.Final_Annualized_Amount__c;
            }
                 acctMap.put(acct.id,acct);
            }
            }
        }
        update acctMap.values();
        }
}
```

Comment: You say that the trigger isn't firing, but it is... because you are seeing the debug output from line 25. What is it that's not working correctly in your code? What do you expect it to be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that if you change this syntax in your trigger everywhere that it is written this way:

```
opp2.Account.Id
```

To

```
opp2.AccountId
```

it will work as you expect.

The data which is in the trigger collection is just the information on the `Opportunity` records themselves not any related data. Your current syntax is traversing from the `Opportunity` object up to the `Account` object through the relationship between them.

If you change the syntax to just use the `AccountId` field directly on the `Opportunity`, you'll likely find a non-null value there.

Comment: You're absolutely right. *Relationships* aren't automatically populated, so `Account.Id` isn't the same as `AccountId`. This is probably the easiest trap to fall in to or second guess yourself on.